# Add Miners in open-ethereum-pool

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mining-pools

I am using open-ethereum-pool for creating the ethereum mining pool over an private ethereum network . but it always give me no. of miners in pool are 0 . How do i add miners in the pool , I do not want to add any hardwares to work as miners . This task is only for testing and learning purpose . I want to use only geth nodes to work as miners or in other words CPU miners .
Please do correct me if i am wrong in my approach

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use a pool. In any case, you can point `geth` at the pool using the `--farm` option and add the `--mine` option to start mining.

```
geth --farm http://youraddress:yourport/yourethereumaddress/nodename --mine
```